# Mongoid many-to-many, is this normal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, many-to-many, mongoid

Here are my models:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  references_many :roles, :stored_as => :array, :inverse_of => :users
  ...
end

class Role
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, :type => String

  references_many :users, :stored_as => :array, :inverse_of => :roles
  ...
end
```

I first create the roles via seed, rake db:seed. My seed file contains:

```
puts '*** Add default roles'
[
  { :name  => 'User' },
  { :name  => 'Artist' }
].each do |h|
  Role.create(h)
end
```

The roles are created successfully. However, when I add a role to a user, I do:

```
foobar = User.first
foobar.roles.create(:name => 'User')
```

I notice 2 things:

1) It adds the role as a reference in the User collection.

2) It creates a 3rd role in the Role collection.

This is kind of strange because now I have 3 roles: User, Artist and User. The 2nd User collection has a user_ids reference which contains foobar's id.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you rather want to do:

```
foobar = User.first
foobar.roles << Role.find(:name => 'User')
foobar.save
```

This way a role object is not created, but a reference is added to an already existing record.

Comment: Yea that seems like its doing it right. By chance, do you know how to remove the reference after you add it with "<<" ?

Comment: @Christian Well, that's a good one. I'm not that experienced Mongoid user, but I'd try `foobar.roles.find(:name => 'User').destroy`. In my opinion that unlinks the two entities, and not destroys the complete role. But definitely test it long before production. :)

Comment: Hmmm. Just tried .destroy and apparently it removes the complete role in Role collection. Thanks for the attempt though :-)

Comment: @Christian Oops, I'm sorry then. :P I'd try `foobar.roles = foobar.roles.except(Role.find(:name => 'User'))` or something similar. Given the amount of roles your app may handle, this doesn't really have a performance penalty, but I'd look up a better solution in a general 1000-to-1000 case.

Comment: Maybe try foobar.roles.delete('whatever your role id is') since delete is a method on array that should just remove the reference.